# Что значит Рефлексивное замыкание?

Tags: математика, множества

вот что такое рефлексивное я знаю, это когда есть бинарное отношение на 1 множестве, например
A = {1,2}
отношение R = {1,2} x {1,2}    = {(1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2)}
тогда (1,1) є R,  и отношение R называеться рефлексивным, но что значит Рефлексивное замыкание?
в источниках написанно что:

---

(R - бинарное отношение на множестве)
рефлексивное замыкание R есть наименьшее рефлексивное отношение на A.

---

в моем случае  рефлексивное замыкание будет (1,1) или как? а если место цифр в моем множестве были бы буквы например то что делать?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сначала уточним определения.

> Бинарное отношение `R` на множестве `A` называется рефлексивным, если для каждого элемента `x` из `A`, `(x, x)` принадлежит `R`.

Обратите внимание, что тут не важно что такое x. Это просто элемент множества А. Т.е. может быть буква, число, розовый слоник и т.д.

Т.е. в вашем примере где `A={1, 2}` и `R = A x A = {(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)}`. Видно, что `R` - рефлексивное отношение, так как и `(1, 1)` и `(2, 2)` входят в `R`.

Теперь определение рефлексивного замыкания:

> Рефлексивным замыканием отношения `R` есть наименьшее рефлексивное отношение на `A`, которое является надмножеством `R`

На практике это означает, что для того чтоб получить из `R` рефлексивное замыкание, нужно туда добавить недостающие элементы вида `(x, x)` (где `x` пренадлежит `A`), которых нет в `R`.

В вашем примере, `R` уже является рефлексивным, а значит его рефлексивное замыкание равно самому `R` (так как ничего добавлять чтоб сделать отношение рефлексивным не нужно).

Рассмотрим другой пример. `A={1, 2, a, b}`, `R = {(1, 2)}`. Тут отношение которое одновременно:

1. есть рефлексивным (т.е. содержит все пары из `A`)
2. содержит все элементы из `R`

это `{(1, 2), (1, 1), (2, 2), (a, a), (b, b)}`. Это и есть рефлексивное замыкание отношения `R`.

Еще хочу ответить на вопросы появившееся в комментариях.

> ну тоесть есть отношение R = {(1, 2)}. оно не являеться рефлексивным замыканием, и мы к нему добавили пару из множества A : (1, 1), (2, 2), (a, a), (b, b) чтоб это отношение стало рефлексивным замыканием?

Скорее всего, вы имеете ввиду правильную идею, но используете не совсем точную терминологию. Неправильно говорить `мы добавляем к множеству R пары, чтобы оно стало рефлексивным замыканием`. Мы не меняем отношение `R`. Мы для отношения `R` находим другое отношение.

То есть можно это рассматривать, как некую операцию "найти рефлексивное замыкание для данного отношения". На вход данной операции подается любое отношение `X` и она выдает результат - новое отношение `Y`. И мы говорм, что `отношение Y является рефлексивным замыканием отношения X`.

Если отношнение Х уже было рефлексивным, то результатом операции "найти рефлексивное замыкакине отношения Х" будет Х.

Если же отношение Х не было рефлексивным, то чтобы найти результат операции "найти рефлексивное замыкание отношения Х", нам нужно построить новое отношение Y взяв все элементы из Х и добавив все пары `(x, x)` для каждого х из А.

Возможно будет полезной аналогия с обычными функциями. Пускай у нас есть операция "найти минимальное целое число не превышающее данное число х". Для числа х=2 ее результатом будет 2 (т.е. мы на вход подали число, которое уже является целым и функция его не меняет, так же как и операция рефлексивного замыкания "не меняет" отношение, которое уже является рефлексивным). Для числа x=3.5 результат будет 3.

Comment: ну тоесть есть отношение R = {(1, 2)}. оно не являеться рефлексивным замыканием, и мы к нему добавили пару из множества A : (1, 1), (2, 2), (a, a), (b, b) чтоб это отношение стало рефлексивным замыканием?

Comment: тоесть рефлексивное замыкание это когда мы добовляем в множеству отношений пару (x,x) с множества?

Comment: Добавил пояснения.

Comment: Я понял - большое спасибо,